# removing the hover of th from bootstrap table hover class

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

all i want is to remove this `<th></th>` hover element. I am using a bootstrap table class table hover and works fine but all i want is to remove the hover in table headers. I tried such many css like this . I am using Bootstrap v3.3.7 (http://getbootstrap.com)

```
.table th:hover {
     background-color: none !important;   
}
```

also this

```
   .table tbody tr:hover th {
  background-color: transparent;
}
```

and etc.

```
.table tbody tr:hover th {
  background-color: transparent;
}
```

Comment: than you for your answer sir. please read my question. I only want to disable hover in table header

Comment: Just a remark: th is childdren of thead tr and not tbody ;)

Answer (score 16, accepted):

From [the documentation](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#tables-hover-rows), Bootstrap only applies a hover effect on table rows if the table has the `table-hover` class, for example:

```
<table class="table table-hover">
    ....
</table>
```

So you just need to remove that class. If you are not able to do that, then you could override with some CSS like this:

```
.table-hover>tbody>tr:hover {
    background-color: #ffffff; /* Assuming you want the hover color to be white */
}
```

Note that any rows in the header *do not* have a hover style applied, but you need to ensure your table looks like this:

```
<table class="table table-hover">
    <thead>
        <tr><th>head cell</th></tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr><td>body cell</td></tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

If your header rows are not at the top of the table, you could also override them with a special class:

```
.table-hover>tbody>tr.no-hover:hover {
    background-color: #ffffff;
}
```

And example of usage:

```
<table class="table table-hover">
    <tr><td>body cell</td></tr>
    <tr class="no-hover"><th>head cell</th></tr>
    <tr><td>body cell</td></tr>
</table>
```

Comment: thank you for your answer sir. I want only to remove the hover in <th></th>

Comment: OK, I've clarified it somewhat. Note that the hover is on `tr`, not `th` or `td` so you need to tell the table which rows are in the header.

Answer (score 2):

to remove the
`<th></th>` 
hover, put the Header `<tr>` inside the `<thead>` tag. And other `<tr>`'s inside the `<tbody>`.

Try this -

```
  <table class="table table-bordered table-hover">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>Firstname</th>
        <th>Lastname</th>
        <th>Email</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td>John</td>
        <td>Doe</td>
        <td>john@example.com</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Mary</td>
        <td>Moe</td>
        <td>mary@example.com</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>July</td>
        <td>Dooley</td>
        <td>july@example.com</td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
```

Answer (score 1):

I think the 'unset' value is what you are looking for.

Add this to your CSS. '!important' might not be necessary, avoid it if you can.

```
.remove-table-hover tr:hover{
   background-color: unset !important;
}
```

Then in your HTML, add the class to your table element.

```
<table class="table remove-table-hover">
...
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

I haven't tested any other Bootstrap versions prior to 5. As for Bootstrap 5 you may just use

```
.table th:hover {
    box-shadow: none;
}
```

Answer (score -2):

```
.table-hover thead tr th:hover, .table-hover thead tr:hover th, .table-hover thead tr:hover td, .table-hover thead tr td:hover
 {
    background-color: none !important;   
}
```

Comment: Hover effect uses `box-shadow`.